# ¿como obtener el valor de los spinner que han sido "inflados" de un layout , en cierta cantidad de ocaciones?

Tags: java, android, spinner

Buenas, estos días he tenido  un problema , Verán  uso `inflate`  para inflar  un layout dentro de otro layout, el layout que inserto  contiene un Spinner   pero el problema  que tengo  es que al querer obtener el id   de los spinner que inserto así sean 4 o 10 el problema es el mismo  , pero al quererlo obtener por el id , solo me toma el valor del  primer spinner que inserte
esta linea del código la utilizo para inflar el layout
`infla = View.inflate(getActivity(),R.layout.nuevos_spinner_materiales,layout);`

El siguiente XML es el que  aparezoo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/tipos_materiales"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cantidadMaterial1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/cantidad"
    android:inputType="number" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho

Comment: En Java, como estas asignando los valores al spinner, recomiendo que edites la pregunta y agregues la actividad donde le asignas el adapter al spinner o al menos lo que tienes para ver como hace para inicializar el spinner.

Comment: los valores se los agrego en el con XML con `android:entries="@array/tipos_materiales"`

Comment: ok ok, imagino que tipos materiales tiene una lista que dice por ejemplo "metal, cemento, arena...." <-- es un ejemplo. Y lo que quieres saber es que cuando se selecciona uno en el spinner poder guardarlo en una variable para posteriormente hacer algo con ese valor. Como por ejemplo mostrar un mensaje que diga "Usted seleccionó metal" es algo así lo que necesita?

Comment: si, pero al  inflar ese layout  por ejemplo 10 veces  obtener esos valores en cada uno  de los Spinners que se insertaron , pero como los inserta con el mismo id que esta definido   en el xml, no se como diferenciar los spinner entre si , ya que todos tienen el mismo id y si lo hiciera con el id siempre me tomaria el valor del primer Spinner que encuentre con ese Id

Comment: porque lo inflas 10 veces? Agrega el código de la actividad editando esta pregunta, no tiene sentido que lo infles 10 veces. Pero tal vez es que no nos estamos entendiendo bien.

Comment: por ejemplo el usuario tiene que  ingresar que materiales ingreso para un trabajo, pera un trabajo puede usar 3 materiales, para otro 2 o para otro 10 y de ahi que se infle para cada  trabajo una cantidad cariable de veces

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71210/discussion-between-gustavo-mora-and-jesussh).